# Change in total gas pressure

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

The question reads:

[image]

For the part were they ask about the total gas pressure, would it be correct to say that the total gas pressure doesn't change? Instead of $0.8$ $atm$ of $N_2O$, it is now $0.8$ $atm$ of various partial pressures of $N_2O$, $N_2$ and $O_2$?

Comment: If you start with 0.8 atm, you won't necessarily end up with that many. You should write up the reaction and look at how many moles are gas are on either side of the equation. You can then interconvert from (pressure reactant) $\to$ (moles reactant) $\to$ (moles product) $\to$ (pressure product) by using the ideal gas law.

Comment: Thanks, I see the flaw in my logic now, since this reaction doesn't produce 1 mole of oxygen and 1 mole of nitrogen it definitely wouldn't be 0.8 atm after. Thank you

Comment: Process is probably isochoric - constant volume not pressure.